# How to call a stored procedure from MVC that requires a list of ids

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, stored-procedures

I got a good answer to my previous question but it's actually even more complicated:

I need to pass to this stored procedure a list of ints:

```
ALTER proc [dbo].[Invoice_GetHomePageInvoices] (
      @AreaIdList varchar(max)
,      @FinancialYearStartDate datetime = null
,      @FinancialYearEndDate datetime = null
```

Here's what I have so far:

```
public virtual IEnumerable<HomePageInvoice> GetHomePageInvoices(IList<Area> areas, FinancialYearLookup financialYear)
{
    var areaIds = areas.Select(x => x.Id).ToList();

    //return _db.Database.SqlQuery<HomePageInvoice>(string.Format("EXEC Invoice_GetHomePageInvoices @AreaIdList = '{0}', @FinancialYearStartDate = '{1}', @FinancialYearEndDate = '{2}'", areas.ToString(), financialYear.StartDate.ToString(), financialYear.EndDate.ToString()));

    var startDate = new SqlParameter("FinancialYearStartDate", financialYear.StartDate);
    var endDate = new SqlParameter("FinancialYearEndDate", financialYear.EndDate);

    return _db.Database.SqlQuery<HomePageInvoice>("Invoice_GetHomePageInvoices", startDate, endDate);
}
```

So the the datetime parameters are sorted. But how would you send the ids to the stored proc given I current have a `List<int>` and sql expects `@AreaIdList varchar(max)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

String.Join?

```
String.Join(",", areaIds)
```

Comment: For a more elegant solution, see my previous answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7487909/621962

Answer (score 1):

Table-valued parameters, you should really read the post below. He does a fantastic job at explaining how it all should work

http://www.sommarskog.se/arrays-in-sql-2008.html

Answer (score 0):

Convert your `List<int>` to a comma-separated string, and pass that to your stored procedure.

[Converting a generic list to a CSV string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1890093/converting-a-generic-list-to-a-csv-string)

Answer (score 0):

I really depends on what you are doing with that list. But if you are using it for an `IN` clause or something like that then I would build that out in C# and pass it to the proc:

```
StringBuilder s = new StringBuilder();
foreach (var i in areaIds)
{
    s.Append(String.Format("'{0}',", i));
}
s.TrimEnd(',');
var areas = new SqlParameter("AreaIdList", s.ToString());
```

Then in the proc you can use it like:

```
WHERE area IN @AreaIdList
```